# How can I repeat text in a manipulative way, and repeat this action until my target has been reached?

Tags: java, loops

How do I count up from 1 to a given number in triangular fashion?

**Attempt**

```
while (numbers <= number) {  
    System.out.println(numbers);
    numbers++;
}
```

**Target Output**

```
1

1 2

1 2 3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Your "attempt" and "target" are just text.  Not logic.  That doesn't tell us anything about what you have tried that is not working

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first post here. I'll edit that real quick if that helps.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the input and expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to get the output display in Target Output, the input would be any desired number 1 or higher, and integers only.

Comment: As you try to learn, we should not give you the solution. Next step after your first trial: try to build a string instead of printing. So you can get a string 1 2 3. Then try to make the both steps together

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read about looping in Java, [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-for-loop) is a base to start from.

```
        int num = 10;
    
    for(int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

This should provide the triangular structure you are looking for. Definitely do take a look at the link above. Since you are new to Java, you should take a walk through this code before simply copying it. Really try to see how it works and more importantly, why it works.